# Program barcode scanner to work in a macOS browser

Tags: macos

Website uses a [standard HTML accessKey property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_accesskey.asp) to move the cursor to specified field and enter scanned barcode. The accesskey being used is <kbd>]</kbd>. I can program the barcode scanner ([Zebra DS2208](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/scanners/general-purpose-scanners/handheld/ds2200-series.html)) to work on the PC web page using Send <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> then send all remaining to program the scanner.

For accesskey to work on a Mac, you must hold <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> for cursor to move to field.
Is it possible to program scanner to send <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>?

Comment: What website???

Answer (score -1):

Question1: the official website is internal, but this site https://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/html_401/article.php/3479621
demonstrates the functionality. Control+Alt+n on a Mac will place the cursor in the Name field

Question2: trying to program the scanner to send Control+Alt+n on the web page (mac) so when a barcode is scanned the cursor goes to the correct field and inserts the barcode